# Least square method to fit a curve using projection/orthogonal families of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

> An object was lanched from a building and had its height registered by
>   the following table:
>
> Height   192    180 150 115 72
>
> Time ---  1  -  2 --- 3 -- 4--- 5
>
> Use the least squares method to estimate the height, $g$ and the
>   vertical velocity at $t=0$

I think I must fit a curve into this dataset. I'm studying orthogonal families of polynomials and projection onto subspaces, so I guess I should use these concepts.

The first question is: which function I should use to approximate to the dataset and how many free parameters I should use?

Comment: A 2nd degree polynomial as the equation for an object in flight is a 2nd-degree polynomial. The equation for displacement is given as $y = v_{y0}t - \frac{1}{2}gt^{2}$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the dynamical model is

$$
\ddot y = -g
$$

we have as general solution

$$
y(t) = -\frac 12 g t^2+c_1 t + c_2
$$

so defining now the measurement error as

$$
e_k^2 = \left(y(t_k) + y_k\right)^2
$$

and calling the total error as

$$
E_2 = \sum_k e_k^2 = f(c_1,c_2,g)
$$

the minimum total error is attained at

$$
\frac{\partial E_2}{\partial c_1} = \frac{\partial E_2}{\partial c_2} = \frac{\partial E_2}{\partial g} = 0
$$

now solving the resulting linear system we get

$$
c_1 = -\frac{25}{14},\ \ c_2 = \frac{999}{5},\ \ g = \frac{67}{7}
$$

now at $t = 0$ we have $y_0 = c_2 = \frac{999}{5}$ and $\dot y_0 = v_0 = c_1 =-\frac{25}{14}$

Attached a plot showing in blue the adjusted function $y(t)$ and in red the measuring points.

[image]